# How to get Unity 5 to recognize "~" button press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just want to add the "~" button to the InputManager so I can enable my dev console like so:

```
public string toggle = "~";
void Update () 
{
   if (toggle == string.Empty) 
   {
      return;
   }
   if (Input.GetButtonDown (toggle)) 
   {
      consoleObject.SetActive( !consoleObject.activeSelf );
   }
}
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that "~" character shares key with "`" in the Mac computers. I just tested and it worked.

```
    if (true == Input. GetButtonDown ("`"))
    {

        Debug.Log ("worked");
    }
```

All you have to do is find the key code for the platform you want (Windows has a key binding with integers).

Thanks.

Comment: I know how to do it with GetKeyDown. I was asking about implementing it with GetButtonDown. They are two different methods.

Comment: My bad. However the two functions take in a string. Sorry for my misunderstanding.